# Disabling QoS Packet Scheduler in Windows Server 2008 via script / command line

Tags: command-line, script, windows-server-2008, qos

Currently you can enable/disable "QoS Packet Scheduler" using Windows GUI.

Right-click on the NIC, Properties.

Is there a way to do this from a command line ? or scripting ? I have many windows server 2008 and would like to be able to enable/disable this feature easily using a script or command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [nvspbind](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nvspbind). To disable "QoS Packet Scheduler" on given network connection use:

```
nvspbind /d "network connection name" ms_pacer
```

To enable, replace /d with /e.